# Django: send email via Office365

Tags: django, smtp, office365

**What I have:**

- A domain purchased in webs.com (I'll call it contoso.com);
- An Office 365 account connected to that domain (my email address is something like `john@contoso.com`);
- A Django application hosted in Azure;

**What I want:**

I would like to configure Django in order to send emails using my `john@contoso.com` address.

**What I'v done:**

I tried this Django configuration:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'john@contoso.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
```

but it didn't work. So, just for a test, I tried the free Google SMTP server:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'john@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yyyyyy'
```

This time it works but, obviously, the email is sent from `john@gmail.com` and not from `john@contoso.com`.

What's wrong in the previous configuration? Or maybe I need to make some changes in my Office 365 account?

---

### Update

So far I've tried to receive emails by setting Django's ADMINS variable in this way:

```
ADMINS = [('Admin Name', 'admin@gmail.com')]
```

And then I send the email using the logging object:

```
logging.error("Hello admin!!")
```

As said, this works only when I use `smtp.gmail.com`. Today I tried to use the `send_mail` function:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'john@gmail.com',
    ['mail@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

And it works both using `smtp.gmail.com` and `smtp.office365.com` configuration. Unfortunatelly this can't be a valid solution for me since I need to notify the admin in case of an error or an exception. So, why the `send_mail` function works with `smtp.office365.com` and the `ADMIN` setting don't?

Comment: That depends on your account configuration. For example, if your account is 2FA enabled, you'll have to use application password instead. Perhaps the better option would be to use Graph API for that (I'm not familiar with Python very much so I won't explain you details). Here's the [SendMail method docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: What error did you get for O365?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send email using the Office365 smtp server, the "from" user and the "host" user must be the same. So I added this setting in Django in order to send email to the admins:

`SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Answer (score 5):

This post is an synthesis of proposals found here.

As per April 2022 this complete configuration works like a charm for native django email configuration:

```
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_HOST", "smtp.office365.com")
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_PORT", 587)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_HOST_USER")
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_USE_TLS", True)
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = os.getenv("APP_EMAIL_TIMEOUT", 60)
```

Then it is just about provisionning the email and password to your application. Additionnaly avoid password with `#` in environment variable in Linux as [they are notably hard to escape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97736/escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment).

Answer (score 3):

It not Django, but just confirm that the SMTP relay is working using PowerShell.  Make sure the From address is the same as the account used to authenticate. Also try using SSL and see.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2w8.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBAd.png]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried to send an email via PowerShell using this instruction `Send-MailMessage -From "john@contoso.com" -to "john@gmail.com" -Subject "subject" -Body "body" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -port "587" -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess` and it works (I used the same credentials used in Django). Unfortunatelly I still can't sent email via Django application.

Comment: I don't get any error neither in Django and nor in Office 365. Anyway I noticed another strange behavior (Update chapter in my question)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of self promotion but I hope it helps:

SMTP authentication is not preferred these days, so I've made an email backend for Django which authenticates through the Office 365 API. You can find it here: https://pypi.org/project/django-o365mail/

Answer (score 0):

After trying for couple of days , the only thing worked for me is :

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```